# How to check if any row of a matrix contains all 'A's?

Tags: c++, arrays, for-loop, if-statement, multidimensional-array

I've been trying to do this, but the problem is that there's always something wrong or missing with the final result.
I have a lot of if statements and I wanted to see if it is possible to reduce it by using a for loop.

```
char matrix[3][3] = {
    {'A','A','A'},{'B','A','B'},{'C','A','C'}
};

if (matrix[0][0] == 'A' && matrix[0][1] == 'A' && matrix[0][2] == 'A') {
            cout << "Found!" << endl;
        }
```

There are a lot more if statements and I didn't put it here because it's the same thing just different index.

I tried to do a for loop like this,

```
for (int i = 0; i < matrix[0][2]; i++) {
            if (matrix[0][0] == matrix[0][1] && matrix[0][0] == matrix[0][2])
                cout << "Found!" << endl;
            break;
        }
```

This looks more organized compared to almost 20 lines of if statements, but it still missing some parts.
For example in the array `[0][1]` and `[1][1]` and `[2][1]` all have the character `'A'`.
How can implement this into the for loop to print out the message when the same character appears in the same line vertically or horizontally.

Comment: You can always go like `bool row_same = true; for(size_t i=0; i<3; i++) { row_same &= matrix[0][i] == 'A'; }` and similar for more complex things.

Comment: @Joe Write out all of your `if` statements manually - I assume you already have them and just copy-pasted them and changed the indices.  Then look at how the indices vary across your if statements, e.g. which ones go from 0 to 2?  Which stay constant?  Then encode that into a for loop.

Comment: I'll bet you that [if you try to explain your `for` loop to your rubber duck](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rubber_duck_debugging), your rubber duck will explain the problem with it. Have you tried explaining your code to your rubber duck yet, and if not why not?

Comment: `for (;matrix[0][0] == 'A' && matrix[0][1] == 'A' && matrix[0][2] == 'A';)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use standard algorithms to express this conveniently:

```
if (std::any_of(std::begin(matrix), std::end(matrix), 
                [](auto const & row) {
                    return std::all_of(std::begin(row), std::end(row), 
                                       [](char c) {
                                           return c == 'A';
                                       });
                }))
{
    std::cout << "Found";
}
```

From C++20, this becomes a little easier to read and write:

```
namespace rs = std::ranges;
if (rs::any_of(matrix, [](auto const & row) {
        return rs::all_of(row, [](char c) {
            return c == 'A';
        });
    }))
{
    std::cout << "Found";
}
```

Here's a [demo](https://godbolt.org/z/7bcdG4)

Comment: This does work and thank you for that. Although, looks something a bit too advance for me at the moment.

Comment: @Joe That's ok, you can learn these techniques when you have the time. Note that `<algorithm>` is a very useful header with a lot of useful tools, so make sure to study it thoroughly.